# set my system date & time via terminal

Tags: debian, date, time, timestamps

I don't why a + sign appears in the my program:

```
 <ns1:ST>2015-05-23T18:00:00+04:00</ns1:ST>
 <ns1:ET>2015-05-23T18:15:00+04:00</ns1:ET>
```

this is when I run the program in my server, which actually prints my current time n date, though it takes the time back 3 hours.

This is the time and date output in my own machine without the + sign

```
 <ns1:ST>2015-05-23T18:15:00</ns1:ST>
 <ns1:ET>2015-05-23T18:30:00</ns1:ET>
```

how can I set the server time with the + sign to my system time format without the + sign? because my program only works in this way without the + sign.

Comment: What is your local time zone? I take it that it's not `+04:00`? If the time is three hours off your local time then I guess you are in something like `+07:00` (south Asia near or around Myanmar, at a quick guess?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write in BIOS, 
Suppose you want to change date strings to the following string:

```
root@debian:/home/mohsen# date -s "Sat May 23 18:56:59 IRDT 2015"
root@debian:/home/mohsen# hwclock -w
```

An first line you set a date, But you need to write in bios, In second line with `hwclock -w` you write your time in bios.